# How to Use The State Management In The Angular 9 Project?

Tags: angular, state-management, ngxs

While i try to use state management in the angular 9 project i can't able to use exactly in my project. Please Anyone help me with An demo example. And also i want to know Which is best state management library in the angular? NGXS, NGRX or.... Other?

Comment: You can look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50704430/difference-in-performance-between-ngrx-and-ngxs

Comment: OK thank you for this comment  but i can't  know exactly how to use state management in the angular real time project